# Float to time conversion in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have one **float** field hours in table for inserting time as following :

```
If 6.3 means 6 hours and 30 minutes
If 8.04 means 8 hours and 4 minutes
```

Now I want to add these all float values to another column new_hours with time format

I need to add entries like following :

```
If 6.3 in hours column then 06:30:00 in new_hours column

If 8.04 in hours column then 08:04:00 in new_hours column
```

I have lot of entries in hours column and i want to add new_hours from hours by one single my sql query.

Any help will be appriciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways; I use the [sec_to_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)
of MySQL which turns a given amount of seconds into a time.

The first step is to convert your floats into seconds (since midnight), then wrap it into `sec_to_time`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select sec_to_time( cast(floor(8.04)*60*60 + ((8.04-floor(8.04))*100*60) as int) );
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sec_to_time( cast(floor(8.04)*60*60 + ((8.04-floor(8.04))*100*60) as int) ) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 08:04:00                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> select sec_to_time( cast(floor(6.3)*60*60 + ((6.3-floor(6.3))*100*60) as int) );
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sec_to_time( cast(floor(6.3)*60*60 + ((6.3-floor(6.3))*100*60) as int) ) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 06:30:00                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to extract the `.04` from `8.04`...

The `update` statement would then be:

```
update t set new_hours = 
   sec_to_time( cast(floor(hours)*60*60 
                   + ((hours-floor(hours))*100*60) as int) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(ROUND(YOUR_COL(i.e. 6.3),2), '.', ':'), '%h:%i %p')
```

Or you can also try this

```
SELECT MAKETIME(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX('6.3', '.', 1),2,0),RPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX('6.3', '.', -1),2,0),00)
```

Comment: Hmm. I liked the one before better.

Comment: Yes, but this1 is to achieve desired output... 0.3 as 30 mins and 0.03 as 3mins.. :p

Comment: Ahh, now I see. I overlooked that in your first attempt.

Comment: found another better(optimized) way :P